# PowerBI refresh data coming from Dataflow

Tags: powerbi

I created a PowerBI report. I edited the report with desktop edition. The report was based on a Data Flow I previously connected to powerBI PRO and then used into PowerBI desktop.
When I publish the report, on PowerBI PRO a new DataSet was created and the report was based on that dataset.

By mistake I deleted the original data flow then I recreated it. The Dataset pointed to the A missing dataflow and I found no way to connect to old dataset and the old report to the new created dataflow.

[image]

Is it possible to change references after dataset are created in the first place? If so how?

Comment: Hi, I don't see how these screenshots help describe your problem. Anyway, are creating the second report based on the dataset or dataflow? So, is the path to the report On-premise -> Dataflow -> Dataset -> Report or On-premise -> Dataset -> Report? Basically, if you want to create second report on the same data, you should live connect to Dataset. If you're connecting to the dataflow, then you're creating another dataset.

Comment: thanks W,B, for your answer I tried to refrase the problem hopping the this could help someone else